# Multillanguage support in Xamarin.Forms application

Tags: xamarin, multilingual

I am trying to develop multi language support in my Xamarin application.
I used 2 Resx files having key value in English and Sweden, and created one global variable for selected language in common `appconfig` class.

I created class `TranslateExtension` which inherits `Imarkupextension` for text conversion according to selected language from `appconfig`.

```
[ContentProperty("Text")]
public class TranslateExtension : IMarkupExtension
  {
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Text == null)
            return null;


        ResourceManager rt1 = new ResourceManager(typeof(Resources.AppResources));
        if (AppConfig.SelectedLanguage == "Swedish")
        {
            rt1 = new ResourceManager(typeof(Resources.AppResources_sd));
        }

        var translation = rt1.GetString(Text);
        return translation;


    }
}
```

Now I am binding its text value like this in XAML page

```
 <StackLayout>
<Picker x:Name="pickerForLanguage"   BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="40" Title="Select Language"  SelectedIndexChanged="SellectedLanguage">
  <Picker.Items>
    <x:String>English</x:String>
    <x:String>Swedish</x:String>
  </Picker.Items>
</Picker>
<Label Text="{resources:TranslateExtension Greeting}"  />
```

Home.xaml.cs

```
 public void SellectedLanguage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pickerForLanguage.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            AppConfig.SelectedLanguage = "English";
        }
        else
        {
            AppConfig.SelectedLanguage = "Swedish";
        }

    }
```

Text gets converted to the selected language from `appconfig` when the page loads for the first time. When I change the language from dropdown, it will change the value of the selected language in `appconfig` only. It will not call `TranslateExtension` value and is not changing after the first time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you never load the english-translation:

```
ResourceManager rt1 = new ResourceManager(typeof(Resources.AppResources_sd));
if (AppConfig.SelectedLanguage == "Swedish")
{
    rt1 = new ResourceManager(typeof(Resources.AppResources_sd));
}
```

For both `ResourceManager` - constructors you set the `AppResources_sd` resources. Change the first line of this code to use the english resource file (something like `AppResources_en`, I think).

And to reduce some overhead, I would load it as shown below:

```
ResourceManager rt1;
if (AppConfig.SelectedLanguage == "Swedish")
{
    rt1 = new ResourceManager(typeof(Resources.AppResources_sd));
}
else
{
    rt1 = new ResourceManager(typeof(Resources.AppResources_en));
}
```

Otherwise you load the swedish resources everytime, altough the user selected english.

Comment: oh.thats not an issue.i just changed that for testing..so forgot to undo it.otherwise i had set english by default and on slected index m chnging it  to sweden.still its not working

Comment: the issue is that code will execute only once whn page loaded.after that on dropdown selection debugger will not go there.so its not changing.thts obvious..but whts the solution.of it.i cnt figure out